# StringBuilder manipulation via Java 8 Streams API

Tags: java-8, java-stream, stringbuilder

I'm struggling to delete some characters from StringBuilder. The method works fine. However, I want to achieve the same via Java-8 streams API. Current code is verbose. Is there any way to refactor second method removeCarryReturnsCharacters() via Java 8 streams API?

```
private static StringBuilder readEntireFileUsingStream(Path filePath) throws IOException {

    StringBuilder data = new StringBuilder(String.valueOf(Files.readAllLines(filePath, StandardCharsets.ISO_8859_1)));

    return removeCarryReturnsCharacters(data);

}

private static StringBuilder removeCarryReturnsCharacters(StringBuilder fileData){

    int endIndex = 1012;
    String needToRemove = "";
    long totDataChunkCount = fileData.length()/1014;
    long delCounter = 1;
    try{
        while (delCounter < totDataChunkCount) {
            needToRemove = fileData.substring(endIndex, endIndex + 2);
            if (needToRemove.equals("^^")) {
                fileData.delete(endIndex, endIndex + 2);
            }
            endIndex += 1012;
            delCounter++;
        }
    }catch(StringIndexOutOfBoundsException exp){
        throw exp;
    }
    return fileData;
}
```

Comment: Can you please simplify your question? What is your usecase? Give some input and desired output so that we can help you

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The current code is not verbose due to the lack of the Stream API, but tons of unnecessary operations:

- the initial assignment `needToRemove = "";` is obsolete
- you are maintaining two redundant loop variables, `delCounter` and `endIndex`
- you are using a `while` loop despite you have a classical counting loop with initial statement, condition and increment operation, the exact thing, `for` loops are made for
- you are using `long` variables for values which definitely never exceed the `int` value range
- you have an obsolete `try … catch` block just re-throwing the caught exception
- you don’t need the `needToRemove` variable to hold an object for a single use; you could simply check `if(fileData.substring(endIndex, endIndex + 2).equals("^^"))` or, as I would prefer for checking just two characters,
  `if(fileData.charAt(endIndex)=='^' && fileData.charAt(endIndex+1)=='^')`

Fixing all these issues will turn the method to

```
private static StringBuilder removeCarryReturnsCharacters(StringBuilder fileData) {
    for(int endIndex = 1012; endIndex < fileData.length(); endIndex += 1012)
        if(fileData.charAt(endIndex) == '^' && fileData.charAt(endIndex+1) == '^')
            fileData.delete(endIndex, endIndex + 2);
    return fileData;
}
```

I don’t think that there will be any additional benefit from rewriting the loop to use the Stream API.

Comment: The educational answer!

Comment: Perfect analysis. Thanks for reviewing and refactoring the code. An educational answer indeed!!

Answer (score 0):

```
private static StringBuilder removeCarryReturnsCharacters(StringBuilder fileData) {
    Stream.iterate(1012, i -> i + 1012)
          .limit(fileData.length() / 1014)
          .sorted(Collections.reverseOrder())
          .forEach(e -> {
                if (fileData.substring(e, e + 2).equals("^^")) {
                    fileData.delete(e, e + 2);
                }
          });
    return fileData;
}
```

Comment: Processing in descending order would help the performance a little bit, but changes the semantics compared to the OP’s code as each `delete` changes indices of the subsequent characters. Since the deletion happens conditionally, it would be very hard to maintain the offset with the Stream API. (I take the OP’s words for granted that the original code “works fine”, so their use case requires the treatment of the indices exactly that way)…

Comment: This method deletes fewer records than the method without streams.
The first answer was quite helpful in code refactoring. You're right, there is no significant benefit of using streams here. Thank-you for code review and suggestions!

Comment: The reason for deletion of fewer records is its iteration in reverseOrder. And therefore the check fileData.substring(e, e + 2).equals("^^") gets failed because of content of my file.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are trying to remove `^^` from individual lines of the original file. You might solve this using only `File.lines` and `Stream.map`:

```
List<String> lines = Files.lines(filePath, StandardCharsets.ISO_8859_1)
.map(line -> {
    if (line.charAt(endIndex) == '^' && line.charAt(endIndex + 1) == '^') {
        return new StringBuilder(line).delete(endIndex, endIndex + 2).toString();
    } else {
        return line;
    }
})
.collect(Collectors.toList());
```

I guess this might have worse performance in comparison with

```
new StringBuilder(String.valueOf(Files.readAllLines(...)))
```

> However [readAllLines](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#readAllLines-java.nio.file.Path-java.nio.charset.Charset-) read all lines into a List, but [lines](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#lines-java.nio.file.Path-java.nio.charset.Charset-)
>   populates lazily as the stream is consumed.

In this case if we use one big 
`StringBuilder` - all data is read **first**  and processed **later**. On the contrary - in case of `File.lines` data is processed and read at **the same time**. After the last line of the file is read and processed by stream pipeline - there will be a list of file lines with `^^` characters removed.